# "No module named zlib" error anytime I use pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm using terminal on mac, and anytime I attempt to use pip, I get the following error message telling me that it cannot find a module named zlib:

---

```
$ pip --version

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 3, in <module>
    import zlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 3, in <module>
    import zlib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
```

---

I've read several SO posts with the same error message, and have tried their solutions, including attempting to install zlib using homebrew, which fails, and updating my Xcode developer tools. I also installed pip earlier using `python get-pip.py`, and it said it installed successfully.

The reason I need pip is to install a package for use on python 2.7, but doing `$ pip install "package-name"` produces the same error as above. I have both Python 2 and 3 installed on my machine, if that helps. I'm kind of new to pip and using the command line in general, and I'm super confused; if anyone could help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @erip: If `pip` is broken, the OP can hardly use it to install the missing packages needed to make it work. For that matter [`zlib` is a Python built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html), so it shouldn't need to be installed. If it's missing, the Python installation is borked. Otherwise, the only obvious problem would be that the OP installed a package (or has a module in their working directory or elsewhere in `sys.path`) that is shadowing `zlib`, and they'd need to get rid of it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "If `pip` is broken" is tricky. OP is referring to pip to install python 2 packages, while the installed pip seems to actually be pip3. Lots of wonkiness.

Answer (score 4):

This is the OP. I was able to fix the issue, and wanted to post my solution here in case it would help others.

Essentially I believe it occurred because Python2 is default on my machine, but pip is by default pointing to resources pertaining to Python3, or something like that. Doing `pip2 --version` instead provided the expected response.

Comment: I resolve it by `ln -sf /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/bin/pip3 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/pip`